# How to select multiple JCheckBoxe into ButtonGroup?

Tags: java, swing, multi-select, jcheckbox, buttongroup

I have three JCheckBox like following:

```
final JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox("A");
final JCheckBox c2 = new JCheckBox("B");
final JCheckBox c3 = new JCheckBox("C");
```

I make a group by ButtonGroup for this checkboxes like following:

```
final ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(c1);
bg.add(c2);
bg.add(c3);
```

I have a Button to display selected items into a label like following:

```
String SelectedItem=""; 
Enumeration<AbstractButton> items= bg.getElements();
while (items.hasMoreElements()) {
    AbstractButton btn = items.nextElement();
if(btn.isSelected())
{
        SelectedItem+=btn.getText()+",";
    }
 }
 lblA.setText(SelectedItem);
```

this work fine , but i cann't select multiple check boxes in run time.

Comment: *" but i cann't select multiple check boxes in run time"*...They're in a button group...that's the point...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of `ButtonGroup` is multiple-exclusive selection. Do not create `ButtonGroup` only if you want to have a collection of your buttons. Instead of `ButtonGroup` use a standard collection like `ArrayList`.

```
List<JCheckBox> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
buttons.add(c1);
buttons.add(c2);
buttons.add(c3);

...

for ( JCheckbox checkbox : buttons ) {
    if( checkbox.isSelected() )
    {
        SelectedItem += btn.getText() + ",";
    }
}
```

Further notices: do updates (`.setText`) in Swing event thread (`invokelater`), remeber that it is better to create StringBuilder in such concatenation, but with UI component quantities like this, performance impact propably will be not noticeable.

Comment: I use ArrayList<JCheckBox> buttons = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>(); and my problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation:

**Class ButtonGroup**

> **This class is used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of
>   buttons.** Creating a set of buttons with the same ButtonGroup object
>   **means that turning "on" one of those buttons turns off all other
>   buttons in the group.**

That said, you probably are using the wrong class to do what you need, if you want to GROUP those checkboxes, put them in a panel, than you can work visibility, position and all other attributes with the panel instead of each checkbox.

Here is the link to documentation: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html)