# Compile error: Package [CarFeatures] does not exists

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a car application which has option to select car features with `JCheckBox` and there are about 30 `JCheckBox`.

As this is a Database Application, I need to get and set selected checkboxes in Database overtime.

On Stack Overflow I found this question which is similar to my requirements but this doesn't work in my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/19246403/4099884

I am adding my check boxes like this:

```
package haams;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class HAAMS {

    JCheckBox AirConditioner = new JCheckBox();;
    JCheckBox ClimateControl = new JCheckBox();;
    JCheckBox AntiLockBrakes = new JCheckBox();;

    List<JCheckBox> CarFeatures = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();

    CarFeatures.add(AirConditioner);  //Error: Package CarFeatures does not exists
    CarFeatures.add(ClimateControl);  //Error: Package CarFeatures does not exists
    CarFeatures.add(AntiLockBrakes);  //Error: Package CarFeatures does not exists

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Why it is saying **Package CarFeatures does not exists**? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define a class first?

Comment: Well done, now define a method

Comment: OK I got it. Thanks Guys. That was little :(

Comment: How stupid of me. Actually I didn't even know this. This is what happens when you just keep using NetBeans Drag and Drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all your code it's not even in a class causing a compiling error. On the other hand method calls should be done in a method/constructor context. These lines:

```
CarFeatures.add(AirConditioner);
CarFeatures.add(ClimateControl);
CarFeatures.add(AntiLockBrakes);
```

Have to be included in class constructor or some other method:

```
public MyClass() {
    CarFeatures.add(AirConditioner);
    CarFeatures.add(ClimateControl);
    CarFeatures.add(AntiLockBrakes);
}

// or

private void addCarsFeatures() {
    CarFeatures.add(AirConditioner);
    CarFeatures.add(ClimateControl);
    CarFeatures.add(AntiLockBrakes);
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know this. Shame on me. Thanks to you. How stupid of me. Actually I didn't even know this. This is what happens when you just keep using NetBeans Drag and Drop

Answer (score 2):

These lines:

```
CarFeatures.add(AirConditioner);  //Error: Package CarFeatures does not exists
CarFeatures.add(ClimateControl);  //Error: Package CarFeatures does not exists
CarFeatures.add(AntiLockBrakes);  //Error: Package CarFeatures does not exists
```

need to be inside a method or a static initializer. Perhaps add a constructor or a `main` method and place the code there.

You should also use `camelCase` for variable names. So `carFeatures` would be the right choice.

Comment: Though I wanted to accept your answer as well but... Thanks anyway